# How to extract substring with regex

Tags: python, regex, pandas

I have SKUs of like the following:

```
SBC225SLB32
SBA2161BRB30
PBA632AS32
```

Where the first 3-4 characters are A-Z, which must be extracted, and the following 3-4 numbers are [0-9], and also have to be extracted.

For the first, I tried `\D{3,4}` and for the second, I tried `\d{3,4}`.

But when using pandas' `.str.extract('\D{3,4}')`, I got a `pattern contains no capture groups` error.
Is there a better way to do this?

Comment: Sorry, I should have made it clear that it doesn't work.

Comment: I edited the question slightly to show this.

Comment: To those who are closing as "Need more focus": the question contains all required details  and is focused on a single issue - there is no reason to close the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The regex pattern you pass to [`Series.str.extract`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.extract.html) contains no capturing groups, while the method expects at least one.

In your case, it is more convenient to grab both values at once with the help of two capturing groups. You can use

```py
df[['Code1', 'Code2']] = df['SKU'].str.extract(r'^([A-Z]{3,4})([0-9]{3,4})', expand=False)
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/uqLtBb/1). Pattern details:

- `^` - start of string
- `([A-Z]{3,4})` - Capturing group 1: three to four uppercase ASCII letters
- `([0-9]{3,4})` - Capturing group 2: three to four uppercase ASCII digits.

Comment: Beautiful! I didn't realize you could extract both at the same time, and also put them into a dataframe in one line!